# how to create a little arrow in a rectangle

Tags: fireworks

I am trying to create a little arrow in the middle of one of the sides of a rectangle. ( like twitter tweet button).

Any ideas how to do it in fireworks cs4 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this and unlike all the answers presented here, they are going to give you more freedom if you want to resize your shape and yes the triangle will be a part of your final shape not a superimposed two shapes.

**Extending a shape with Pen tool**

First, start with a rectangle. It can have rounded corner, however you like it. Then, you can either ungroup it or selecting the subselection tool (the white arrow in the tools panel) and clicking on one of the corners, you can make it editable for the Pen tool. Then, choosing the Pen tool, click three times on the left side of the rectangle, creating three points apart from each other along the edge. Back to subselection tool and select the middle one. Clicking a few times on the left arrow key on your keyboard will make it go to left. Since we are altering the base shape, your new shape can receive further filters, stroke colors etc.

**Adding your shape to another shape**

Create your rectangle and triangle shape anyway you want to see it. Position triangle so the right of it is just over the left edge of the rectangle. Give it 1-2 px of intersection area if you want, you'll most likely play with this approach to have best results. Both objects selected, go to Modify menu and select Union under Combine Paths. This option will merge both shapes. Since, FW is going to approximate both object styles, you can a blurred stroke if you already had strokes in your objects. You can adjust it but some people thing the method described above is better since they are editing the original image so it's more constructive than guessing the outcome of this merging operation. As usual, using the Pen tool, you can refine your shape.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

This question really doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, but I'll answer anyway, since I'm not sure where it should go.

If this is what you mean: 
[image]
then try this:

1. Create a small triangle.
2. Rotate the triangle 90 degrees to the left, so that it looks like the arrow.
3. Position the triangle on the side of the rectangle.
4. Change the triangle's color to the same color as the rectangle.

Comment: That would work, but the rectangle has a border. How would you remove the border from the Triangle base ?

Comment: Put the triangle on top of the rectangle so it just barely overlaps the border of the rectangle. Then there are two ways to do it: 1. Modify the triangle border to only cover two sides (if Fireworks provides an option for that) or 2. Create a small, borderless rectangle the same color as the background of the button and position it over the border of the triangle so that you can no longer see the out of place border.